# Set state value depending on other states

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have some `useState` hooks which evaluate to `true`/`false`. Is there a way to have a string `useState` hook that updates its state to values depending on the most recent hook that evaluates to true?

An example situation might be:

```
stateA = false  
stateB = true  
set stringState = "B"  
stateA = true  
set stringState = "A"
```

Comment: Use useEffect to updated the new state based on the other states

Comment: Sounds like the case of a [XY problem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Comment: What are you _actually_ trying to do here? As in, please show, with some kind of [mcve] what it is you're really doing. Because it sounds like you're simply tracking your state in an incomplete way, where you're current setting those boolean flags without also updating the `stringState` value _at the same time_.

Comment: apologies, I realise I've not given enough detail (and definitely fallen into that XY problem scenario)!
I have a nav menu that highlights icons depending on which section the webpage is at (using intersection observer api) - this is done through states - where true means the icon is highlighted. However, if two sections are small enough then multiple icons are highlighted. 
I was looking for a way to make it so that the highlight would be exclusive, so that only 1 icon could be active at a time - so I assumed this would be one way to do it (by setting the highlight based on the stringState)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're probably looking for is React's `useEffect` hook.

For example, if you're using two variables, `a` and `b`, and want to update stringState to be "A" when `a` is true, "B" when `b` is true and `a` is false, and "C" when none is true, ie `newStringState = a ? "A" : (b ? "B" : "C")` (if `a` (is true) then "A", else if `b` (is true) then "B" else "C"), you can use the useEffect hook as follows:

```
const [a, setA] = React.useState(false)
const [b, setB] = React.useState(false)
const [stringState, setStringState] = React.useState("C")

React.useEffect(() => {
    // Code will run whenever a dependency (a or b) changes
    setStringState(a ? "A" : (b ? "B" : "C")
}, [a, b])
```

See [this link](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) for more details on the `useEffect` hook.

Depending on your implementation, you'll most likely not need `stringState` at all: you can directly put the condition in your components.